# ASP.Net Blazor Exception on ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService when I compile in container

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a problem with my apps (Blazor app) when I compile in container. In my `Program.cs`, i use a Scope for create the database at start :

```cs
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // Vrai si la base de données est créée, false si elle existait déjà.
    if (db.Database.EnsureCreated())
    {
        var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        DataInitializer.InitData(roleManager, userManager).Wait();
        
        // Pour créer le schéma de la base
        var hermesCtx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IHermesContext>();
        string pathSql = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Scripts", "ConsultantsDb.sql");
        await hermesCtx.CreateTablesAsync(pathSql);
    }
}
```

When I run in debug, there is no problem, this line throw no Exception :
`var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>(); --> line 115`
the service was returned, **but** when I "containerize" the app, I have this Exception :

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
Unhandled exception. MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 433
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 363
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 94
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 124
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 915
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 406
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 369
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.AutoDetect(String connectionString)
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>$>b__0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in /src/Hermes/Program.cs:line 39
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<AddDbContext>b__0(IServiceProvider p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /src/Hermes/Program.cs:line 115
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

If anyone have any idea.
Its .NET 6 and the source code is on github : [Hermes project](https://github.com/AnthonyRyck/Hermes/)
Build local image :
`docker build --file dockerfile --tag test/hermes:latest .`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be DI-related on the surface, but the real problem is that your code cannot connect to the database from the container. If you follow the stack trace, you can see that the relevant error message reads:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Please check whether you have configured the connection information correctly and whether it is picked up by the application.

Comment: When I am in DEBUG in IIS Express, I have no problem, as soon as I am on Docker I have the exception. I added a Trace to see if the connection string is the same, and yes.

Answer (score 0):

I found, it's my fault, you have right @Markus.
My connection string is :
`server=127.0.0.1;port=3305;user id=root;password=PassHermesDb;database=testhermes`
but when I use Docker, localhost is not my database, it's my container.
I have to use the IP of my machine, 192.168.xxx.xxx